# Tableau calling a REST API to redact a cell

Tags: rest, tableau-desktop

I would like to understand how I could call external REST API from a Tableau workbook to decide how the content of a report (or a cell) should be displayed.

Say I am generating a report, and this report contains several columns, one being the name of an asset, another one being an asset type and another being an asset value.

I am accessing these data from a given data source. I need to modify the name of the asset that is being displayed if the result of an external call returns a given value.

e.g. I have two rows:
Asset1 AssetType1 1000
Asset2 AssetType1 2000

I need to call a rest API, and pass the asset type and the value, and if this API returns true then I have to modify the Asset Name, so that the result would look like:
Asset1 AssetType1 1000
RedactedAsset AssetType2 2000

I am new to Tableau. It seems that I can implement an extension to do it, but cannot find any good documentation.
It would be great if somebody could explain what the best approach to implement this kind of requirement is.

Regards

G